# When can two elementary end extensions of models of PA be uniquely amalgamated?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

$\DeclareMathOperator{Cod}{Cod}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{Scl}{Scl}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{Def}{Def}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{Lt}{Lt}$

**Background:**

All of the background to this question can be found in Kossak-Schmerl, *The Structure of Models of Peano Arithmetic* (2006) (referred hereafter as [KS]), section 2.3. I will try to summarize as much as needed for this question. Given a model $M \models \mathsf{PA}$, and elementary extensions $M_1$ and $M_2$ of $M$, an amalgamation of $M_1$ and $M_2$ over $M$ is a model $N \succ M$ along with elementary embeddings $f_i : M_i \to N$ such that the intersection of the images of the $f_i$ is exactly $M$. We are particularly interested in when $N$ is generated by the images of the $f_i$; up to isomorphism, we let each $f_i$ be the identity, so $M \prec M_1, M_2 \prec N$, and $N = \Scl(M_1 \cup M_2)$.

In general, models of $\mathsf{PA}$ do not have unique (up to isomorphism) amalgamations: Theorem 2.3.1 of [KS] shows an example of a (countable) model $M$, along with elementary end extensions $M_1, M_2$ such that there are continuum-many non-isomorphic amalgamations of $M_1$ and $M_2$ over $M$. I am interested in studying when, given a model $M$, and elementary end extensions $M_1$ and $M_2$, $M_1$ and $M_2$ can be uniquely amalgamated over $M$.

Recall the following definitions:

1. $M \prec_\text{end} N$ is an elementary end extension if for each $a \in N \setminus M$ and $b \in M$, $N \models b < a$.
2. $M \prec_\text{cons} N$ is a conservative elementary extension if for every $X \subseteq N$ definable with parameters in $N$, $X \cap M$ is definable with parameters in $M$.

The result in Kossak-Schmerl mentioned above is an example where $M \prec_\text{end} M_1, M_2$, but neither elementary extension is conservative. Every conservative elementary extension is an end extension, and so in [KS, Theorem 2.3.2], they note that if one of the elementary end extensions is conservative, then there is a unique amalgamation (up to isomorphism). In particular, if $M_2$ is a conservative extension of $M$, and $M_1$ is an end extension, then there is a unique amalgamation $N$ of $M_1$ and $M_2$ over $M$ such that $M \prec_\text{end} M_1 \prec_\text{end} N$. (I believe this result is due to Blass, "Conservative Extensions of Models of Arithmetic" (1980)).

Conservativity can be characterized in terms of *coded sets*. Let $M \prec N$. Then $\Cod(N / M) = \{ X \cap M : X \in \Def(N) \}$. Clearly $\Def(M) \subseteq \Cod(N / M)$ whenever $M \prec N$. The definition of conservativity can then be stated: $M \prec_\text{cons} N$ if and only if $\Def(M) = \Cod(N / M)$.

**Question:**

Let $M \prec_\text{end} M_1, M_2$. For any amalgamation $N$ of $M_1$ and $M_2$ over $M$ such that $M \prec_\text{end} M_1 \prec_\text{end} N$, we must have $\Cod(N / M) = \Cod(M_1 / M)$; so for this to be possible, it must be the case that $\Cod(M_2 / M) \subseteq \Cod(M_1 / M)$. Indeed, this is exactly what happens when $M \prec_\text{cons} M_2$. Suppose we do know that $\Cod(M_2 / M) \subseteq \Cod(M_1 / M)$; do we then know that there is a unique amalgamation $N$ of $M_1$ and $M_2$ over $M$, such that $M_1 \prec_\text{end} N$?

Originally, I hoped we could modify the proof given by Blass (and recreated in [KS]). The idea of that proof is that, if $M_2$ is a conservative extension of $M$, then for every formula $\phi(x, y)$ (containing parameters from $M$) and every $b \in M_2$, there is a formula $\sigma(x)$ (with parameters from $M$) such that for each $a \in M$, $M_2 \models \sigma(a) \leftrightarrow \phi(a, b)$. We would then consider the theory $\{ \phi(a, b) : a \in M_1, b \in M_2, M_1 \models \sigma(a) \}$, and the amalgamation would be the prime model of this theory (in the language with all the constants from $M_1$ and $M_2$).

Unfortunately, I do not see a way to modify this proof in the case that $M_2$ is a conservative extension of $M$, even if $\Cod(M_2 / M) \subseteq \Cod(M_1 / M)$. My thinking was that, since for each $\phi(x, y) \in \mathcal{L}(M)$ and each $b \in M_2$, there are $\sigma(x, y) \in \mathcal{L}(M)$ and $a \in M_1$ such that for all $m \in M$, we have $M_2 \models \phi(m, b) \iff M_1 \models \sigma(m, a)$, then we could define the theory $T$ of the amalgamation similarly. However, in this case, for each $\phi$, we may have many such $\sigma$, and there does not seem to be a canonical way to choose one.

Follow-ups:

1. Is this question any different if we assume that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are finitely generated extensions of $M$?
2. More generally: are there any conditions known, for $M \prec_\text{end} M_1, M_2$ in which the extensions are not conservative, but there is a unique amalgamation $N$ of $M_1$ and $M_2$ over $M$ such that $M_1 \prec_\text{end} N$?

**Additional Context**

Jim Schmerl ("Minimal elementary end extensions" 2017) had characterized those sets which could arise as $\Cod(N / M)$ for some *minimal* elementary end extension $N \succ_\text{end} M$. It is not hard to extend this result to get $M \prec_\text{end} N_1$ such that $\Cod(N_1 / M) = \Cod(N / M)$ and $N_1$ has exactly two intermediate models between it and $M$: $N$ and a conservative, minimal elementary extension $M_1$ of $M$. In this case, the *interstructure lattice* between $M$ and $N_1$, denoted $\Lt(N_1 / M)$, is isomorphic to the Boolean algebra on 2 elements, $\mathrm{B}_2$. $N_1$ is the amalgamation of $N$ and $M_1$ over $M$. Jim asked, given such an $M$ and $N$, if it is possible to find an $N_1$ with similar properties (ie, $\Cod(N_1 / M) = \Cod(N / M)$, and $\Lt(N_1 / M) \cong \mathrm{B}_2$), except that neither of the intermediate models is conservative (assuming that $N$ itself is not, of course).